# MySQL COUNT() and duplicates

Tags: mysql, count

I have this query:

```
select count(name) as nr  
from team where city='ny' and name=ANY  
(select teamName from contract where playerCode=ANY  
(select code from player where name='X' and surname='Y'));
```

I don't understand why the count() function doesn't count the duplicates even if there is no distinct clause.

These are the tables:

```
Player(code, name, surname)  
Contract(id, playerCode, teamName, year)  
Team(name, city)
```

With this integrity constraints:

```
Contract(playerCode)-->Player(code)  
Contract(teamName)-->Team(name)
```

The query extracts the number of teams of NY city which have a contract with a player named X,Y.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you get for it, and explain how this differs from the result you'd like to get?

Comment: I don't understand your query  .. what means the  two subquery  ..you want cartesian product from these tables ) .. show a proper sample please

Comment: In my experience, `count()` does count duplicates in the absence of `distinct`.  Maybe, once those two `ANY` subqueries are done, there actually are no duplicates to be counted?

Comment: The result is what I wanted to achieve, this is just a mere curiosity because in other situations I noticed that the count() function normally counts the duplicates.

Comment: What do you get if you say `select * from team`... rather than `select count(name) as nr  from team` ... ? I bet you get no duplicate rows.

Comment: I also don't see where you get duplicates. I mean, for each team the where clause is evaluated ... it doesn't get evaluated twice or something ... so exactly once.

Comment: If there is a team of NY city which has 2 or more contracts with the player X,Y, it's counted always as one. 
In this case it's a desirable behaviour, but normally I know that count(*) or count(something) counts always also the duplicates, unless there is the distinct clause.
In my case, there is no difference if I use count(*) or count(name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will count duplicates. My guess is that you are expecting duplicates from multiple matches in the subquery. However, the subquery is not a JOIN and so will not be duplicating results from the `team` table, regardless of how many matches there are in the subquery.

Each row in the `team` table will only have the `WHERE` conditions evaluated once, and will be included (once) based on whether those conditions are satisfied.

Assuming there are no NULL values in `team.name`, if you `SELECT COUNT(name), COUNT(*)` both fields should have the same value.

Comment: I can assure you my query doesn't count duplicates, I tried by inserting two different contracts with the same player (x,y) and the same NY city team and they are counted as one. Nevertheless, I also tried running a similar query made with join and it counts the duplicates, so I guess it is a matter of how sql interprets the subqueries.

Comment: @user3515916 you are not counting contracts, you are counting teams; it does not matter how many contracts a team has that match those conditions, the team will only ever be counted once. (You are counting `name` in `team`, not `teamName` in `contract`.)

Comment: Well, then I don't understand why if I do the same thing in this query:

`select count(t.name) from team as t, contract, player as p where t.name=teamName and p.code=playerCode and t.city='NY' and p.name='X' and p.surname='Y';`
I do obtain duplicates.

Comment: @user3515916 That is a join, using archaic and discourage syntax, which combines fields from the tables referenced. If you compare the results of both queries, without the aggregation (just `SELECT t.name...`) the difference, in these "intermediate" results that actually end up being what is counted, should become apparent. _COUNT is processed after JOINs and WHEREs_

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. I did as you asked but the result is pretty obvious: in the first case, with the inner join, I have as first result the name of the "duplicates", in the second case, with the subqueries, for first I have the non-duplicate team. I can only guess that the "problem" is not in the count clause but in the way SQL interprets joins and subqueries.

Comment: @user3515916 Correct, mostly; the difference comes from how JOINs and WHEREs are handled. A JOIN will match up every row on the left with every row on the right (when the ON conditions are met); multiple matches on either side result in duplicated data from the other side. With WHERE, rows are chosen based on whether they satisfy the conditions of the WHERE, they are not matched up (JOINed) with rows from anything used in the WHERE conditions. Expecting duplication from a WHERE would imply things like `WHERE id IN (1, 1)` should result in 2 copies of rows with id = 1; which isn't how it works.

Comment: To put it another way, `SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE [any conditions you can think of]` will never result in more than one copy of any particular row in "tableA". `SELECT * FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON 1=1` results in a number of copies of the data in each row of tableA equal to the number of rows in tableB (since 1=1 means match every row against every row); and vice versa.

Comment: God bless you, my friend: it's finally crystal clear!